# Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java

I am getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at sorting.main(sorting.java:53). I am just trying to pass string integer values to an integer array but it is not working as intended. I have variables above such as `count` which is determined by how many integers the user wants to enter. In and another variable `int[] list = new int[count];` which is the integer array I am trying to pass them to. If I enter the value of `5` for count I am trying to only accept 5 values of integers. Passing them to the `int[] list` array is where I am messing up.

```
// Prompts user to enter the integer values here
while(true){
   System.out.print("\nEnter integer values here seperated by a space: ");
   intValues = input.readLine();
   String[] intCheck = intValues.split("\\s+");

   try {
      for(int j = 0; j < intCheck.length; j++){
           list[j] = Integer.parseInt(intCheck[j]);     // LINE 53 IS HERE
      }
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.err.println("You need to enter valid integer numbers. Try again.");
   }     
}
```

Comment: Your `intCheck` array is larger than the `list` array. That's all.

Comment: Show us your `list` declaration .. and take `ArrayList` not `Int Array` so that it will increases its size dynamically ..

Comment: I don't understand how

Comment: Where is the list declaration? Robby is probably right, you need to make sure that list.length >=intCheck.lenght

Answer (score 0):

you probably have an extra space at the end so your split is returning an overlarge array. Use j < count.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten my error. I declared `int count = 0` early on. Then just below that I declared `int[] list = new int[count]` which was taking 0 values. I should have declared the range after I prompted the user to enter the information.